# Run command for each line of variable in cmd

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, split

I want to run a command (in this example `echo`) for each line of a variable (in `cmd`, i.e. batch). In this case, the lines are supposed to be separated by `\n`, but others delimiters should work as well.

Therefore I set a variable:

```
> set var="foo\nbar"
```

I then want to run my command (`echo`) on each line, i.e. on "foo" and "bar". I tried to use `for` for this:

```
> for /f "tokens=* delims=\n" %s in (%var%) do (echo %s)
foo\nbar
```

Obviously this isn't what I wanted - I expected something like

```
foo
bar
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are aware that `set var="foo\nbar"` doesn't add a line feed between foo and bar? It's just the two characters "\" and `n`. That's also the cause why `delims=\n` will split at "\" and any `n`. Btw.  `FOR /F delims` is for splitting tokens, it will not create more loops

Comment: @jeb it is the same though for a delimiter like `;`: `set var=foo;bar & for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %s in ("%var%") do (echo %s)` yields `foo;bar`. Also I don't understand your BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a real line feed character to get your desired effect.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=empty, do not modify this line=%
)

set "var=foo!\n!bar"

for /f "delims=" %%L in ("!var!") do (
  echo ## %%L
)
```

**Other delimiters in the variable**
can be used, but have to be replaced later with a linefeed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=empty, do not modify this line=%
)

set "var=my,list,delimited,by,commas"

for %%L in ("!\n!")  do (
  for /f "delims=" %%k in ("!var:,=%%~L!") do (
    echo ## %%k
  )
)
```

**About the delims option in FOR /F**

The delims option is for splitting a line into tokens, that will not create more loop iterations - NEVER.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%A in ("123;456;789") do echo ... %%A, %%B, %%C
```

Output

> ... 123, 456, 789

not

> ... 123
> ... 456
> ... 789

Comment: I don't care about the delimiter, I just want to run a command for a set of the input, delimited by something. Maybe it's easiest if you provide an example for `;`.

Answer (score 2):

`%var%` is used as the input set to `FOR`-parcer.
But before running `FOR` command we should replace `\n` with space (+outer quotes):

> Syntax: %variable:StrToFind=NewStr%

Theese spaces become delimiters in our `FOR`-parser.

To remove quotes automatically from a a single letter variable use symbol `~`

> Syntax: %~1

So we have next code:

```
set var="foo\nbar"
for %%A IN (%var:\n=" "%) DO @ECHO=%%~A
```

P.S. As [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) truly said the code won't work correctly with special symbols: `*`, `?`, `%%` in variable content.

Comment: How does this work? Could you give an explanation?

Comment: One small drawback of the *normal* `FOR`, it fails if `*` or `?` are in the list

Comment: So this won't work if var contains spaces?

Comment: My mistake. It shall works. But when the parser meets other special symbols it shall fail.